# Using ASP.NET 5 Packages in ASP.NET 4.5 Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an interest in using some of the ASP.NET 5 packages like [Logging](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging) and [Dependency Injection](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection) in a ASP.NET 4.5 (MVC5) project running on .NET 4.5. I have successfully installed both packages from nuget and appear to be able to use them just fine. Is there a reason why I shouldn't do this (other than the fact that they are in beta of course)?

Comment: You should be fine to using the Logging abstractions. Something like Dependency Injection is a little more complex

Answer (score 0):

One reason not to use ASP.NET 5 Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC is that it does not provide a lot of the features required by ASP.NET 4.6 to get it working. E.g.

1. There is no Dependency Resolver implementation. You have to write your own.
2. Types like the UrlHelper are not automatically registered for you. You have to do this yourself.

Something like Autofac will do this for you and is designed to work with ASP.NET 4.6. Here is an example class using Autofac to get you started:

```
/// <summary>
/// Register types into the Autofac Inversion of Control (IOC) container. Autofac makes it easy to register common 
/// MVC types like the <see cref="UrlHelper"/> using the <see cref="AutofacWebTypesModule"/>. Feel free to change 
/// this to another IoC container of your choice but ensure that common MVC types like <see cref="UrlHelper"/> are 
/// registered. See http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/aspnet.html.
/// </summary>
public partial class Startup
{
    public static void ConfigureContainer(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        IContainer container = CreateContainer();
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

        // Register MVC Types 
        app.UseAutofacMvc();
    }

    private static IContainer CreateContainer()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>().InstancePerRequest();

        // Register Common MVC Types
        builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();

        // Register MVC Filters
        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

        // Register MVC Controllers
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        return container;
    }
}
```